# How to add a plus sign to a button with a list using css

Tags: jquery, html, css

[image]I m trying to add a plus sign to a button with a list which will populate a list when we hower mouse on that button using css.

Comment: please, post some code, to see what you already have

Comment: And an example of what you want

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. please add some code to create a [mcve]

Comment: also your question is unclear. You want to add the plus sign on the button when you click on it, or you just want to add a plus to a button ? see fontAwesome for that

Answer (score 0):

There are template glyphicons for bootstrap. You can use this one if you like the design. 
https://www.w3schools.com/icons/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_glyph_plus-sign
Make sure you have a link to a bootstrap file or cdn

Answer (score 0):

You can use Bootstrap or Font Awesome glyphicons in order to get the '+' icon. Without any actual code though it's hard to know exactly what you're looking for.

If you're looking for something to appear when you hover this icon then this can be easily done using CSS.

```
#list-button{
    opacity:0;
}

#list-button:hover{
    opacity:1;
    transition: .5s ease;
}
```

Apologies for any formatting errors, typed this on my phone.